# CSS Grid Layout number out by 1

Tags: css, grid-layout

With my grid I am finding that for it to work it has to be out by 1, the following is the only way the 3 sections are spread evenly across the page, if I make it 10,fr it has a gap on the right of the screen

```css
.contact-information {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(9,1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(90px, auto);
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.contact-left-section{
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    background-color: red;
}
.contact-middle-section{
    grid-column: 4/7;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    background-color: blue;
}
.contact-right-section{
    grid-column: 7/10;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section class="about light contact-information">
    <div class="contact-left-section">
      <div class="section-title">Phone</div>
        <div class="section-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-middle-section">
      <div class="section-title">Services</div>
        <div class="section-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-right-section">
      <div class="section-title">Email</div>
        <div class="section-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: If you have 3 sections and you want them to be evenly spaced you need to have a number of columns that is divisible by 3. So 3, 6, 9, 12. With the approach you have taken, you also need to adjust the grid-column property as well.

Comment: Yes I have it as 9 in the grid layout but when I do the 3 sections by 3,6 and 9 it leaves one section on the right, the only thing fixing it is 10 which makes no sense

Comment: It makes perfect sense, please read into CSS grids to better understand why your code is correct: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ There's some visuals to help understand it.

Comment: Ok so it is correct meaning you require 1 above grid layout? I will read the document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid) has a detailed dive into this but to give you quick visual understanding of why 10 is correct. When you are defining the grid-column you are picking the start and end position based on the image below.

Hope this visually helps you better understand what is going on.

[image: 9 column grid]